# How to detect if device is a phone with display or a camera with no display?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have developed an android app and its working fine on android mobile phone and tab. Now I want to run this app on android camera with no display for which I have to do some changes in code. But I don't know how to distinguish between them from code. So that I can run some code for android phone with display and some code for android camera with no display.

Please help.

Comment: `packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_EMBEDDED)` will tell you if it's Android Things. Do you know that the Things device will always not have a display or do you need to check that?

Comment: @JediBurrell I have to register android device. for android phone I have register layout that I will show and for android camera device as I don't have display so I want to register that by scanning QR code. For that only I need to know what kind of device I'm dealing with.   thanks for your reply I will try that....

Comment: @JediBurrell  this is not working always returning false for both device types

Comment: Try `android.hardware.type.embedded`.